# Filtering by category to print in php

Tags: php, sql

I'm making a report where i need to filter details by category. I have two categories in my itr table which are Resident and 4Ps.

So far, this is my code. I can print all the details of the itr table here.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style = "padding-right:80px;padding-left:150px;">
    <center>Name</center></th>
    <th style = "padding-right:10px;padding-left:15px;"><center>Age</center>
    </th>
    <th style = "padding-right:10px;padding-left:20px;">
    <center>Gender</center></th>
    <th style = "padding-right:30px;padding-left:40px;">
    <center>Purok</center></th>
 </tr>
 <?php
   $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM itr LIMIT 30") or 
   die(mysqli_error());
   for($a = 1; $a <= 30; $a++){
     $fetch = $query->fetch_array()
 ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $a.". ".$fetch['firstname']." ".$fetch['firstname']?></td>
  <td><center><?php echo $fetch['age']?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php echo $fetch['gender']?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php echo $fetch['address']?></center></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

What I want is to print only those who are in 4Ps category using a button like "Filter by Category" where i can choose to filter by resident or 4Ps so that i can use only one php file. I don't know what how to do it. Please Help :)

this is the html of for category

```
<label for = "category">Please select category:</label>
    <select style = "width:22%;" class = "form-control" name = "category" required = "required">
        <option value = "">--Select category--</option>
        <option value = "RESIDENT">RESIDENT</option>
        <option value = "4Ps">4Ps</option>
    </select>
<br />
```

This is my itr table:

[image: itr table]

And this is my desired output:

[image: output]

Comment: does the `itr` table have a column that defines the category? if so you can change your SQL to `SELECT * FROM itr WHERE category = '4Ps' LIMIT 30`.

Comment: Hi thanks :) i just edited my question :)

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? How to write SQL query or how to control it with button?

Comment: `I have two categories in my itr table which are Resident and 4Ps.` - This is unclear, I don't understand. can you tell us the structure of itr?

Comment: Also, do you want to *Sort* by category, or *Filter* by category?

Comment: Filter. Im soryyy

Comment: @Cashbee under itr: itr_no, last, middle, first, bday, age, category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You need to put category-select-box  inside a form

2.When user submits the form based on coming category,query need to be changed.

***So do like below:-***

```
<form method="POST">

    <label for = "category">Please select category:</label>
    <select style = "width:22%;" class = "form-control" name = "category" required = "required">
        <option value = "">--Select category--</option>
        <option value = "RESIDENT">RESIDENT</option>
        <option value = "4PS">4Ps</option> <!-- changed option value to capitals-->
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th style = "padding-right:80px;padding-left:150px;">
    <center>Name</center></th>
    <th style = "padding-right:10px;padding-left:15px;"><center>Age</center>
    </th>
    <th style = "padding-right:10px;padding-left:20px;">
    <center>Gender</center></th>
    <th style = "padding-right:30px;padding-left:40px;">
    <center>Purok</center></th>
 </tr>
 <?php
   if(isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] !==''){
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM itr where category = '$category' LIMIT 30") or die(mysqli_error());
   }else{
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM itr LIMIT 30") or die(mysqli_error());
   }
   for($a = 1; $a <= 30; $a++){
     $fetch = $query->fetch_array()
 ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $a.". ".$fetch['firstname']." ".$fetch['firstname']?></td>
  <td><center><?php echo $fetch['age']?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php echo $fetch['gender']?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php echo $fetch['address']?></center></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

***Note:-*** Your code is wide-open for SQL INJECTION. to prevent from it use `prepared statements`

***Reference:-***

[mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

[PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: i tried this code and i get this error >Unknown column 'RESIDENT' in 'where clause' :(

Comment: @TechieMickey  in your table what values  saved inside `category` column for different records? please tell.

Comment: @AlivetoDie i'll attach the photo in my question :)

Comment: @TechieMickey  use my edited solution.I have changed it based on table picture

Comment: Yay! Thank you so much @AlivetoDie ! it works totally fine now :) More power to you :)

Comment: Yay! Thank you so much @AlivetoDie ! it works totally fine now :) More power to you :)

Comment: @TechieMickey  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

Although I prefer AliveToDie's solution I want to give you an alternative that does not refresh the page on category selection.

You could show and hide columns with javascript when you change the value of your category select.
For that you need to give the tr's a class with the category name

```
<!-- table with id for easy js  -->
<table id="itr_table">

<!-- table headers... -->

<!-- table body -->
<tr class="tr_body tr_<?php echo $fetch['category'] ?>">
  <td><?php echo $a.". ".$fetch['firstname']." ".$fetch['firstname']?></td>
  <td><center><?php echo $fetch['age']?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php echo $fetch['gender']?></center></td>
  <td><center><?php echo $fetch['address']?></center></td>
</tr>


<!-- category select, I added a changelistener -->
<select style = "width:22%;" class = "form-control" name = "category" required = "required" onchange="filterByCategory(this)">
    <option value = "">--Select category--</option>
    <option value = "1">RESIDENT</option> <!-- the value should be the actual id of the category. -->
    <option value = "2">4Ps</option>
</select>

<!-- javascript -->
<script>
filterByCategory(selectElement){
    category = $(selectElement).value();

    //hide all trs
    $('#itr_table .tr_body').hide();

    //show trs with chosen category
    $('#itr_table .tr_'.category).show();
}
</script>
```

Please note that this is not tested and may have some errors. I just wanted to give you an idea on how to approach the problem.